# SQL Server Express support for TLS1.2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-express, tls-1.2

I have installed SQL Server 2014 Express Edition ( 12.0.2000.8 x64 ) on a Windows server 2012 machine.

Because of the POODLE vulnerability, our IT department is going to disable TLS 1.0 and all other previous security protocols on this server.

Where can I find a newer version of SQL server Express Edition that can support OR work with TLS 1.2?

Answer (score 2):

You don't strictly need a newer version of SQL Server; however as a general thing I always prefer to be using the most recent version (especially in this case, because in SQL Server 2016 SP1, you get [all kinds of new features in Express Edition](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1)).

You do need to apply one of the following updates, though (I go through more details in [this blog post](https://sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/tls-1-2-support-read-first/)). They are listed in my order of preference:

- [**Service Pack 2**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53168) (+ [SP2 CU#3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53592), ideally)
- [Service Pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3058865) + [SP1 GDR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=3098852&kbln=en-us) (minimum) (+ [SP1 CU#10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51186), ideally)
- [RTM CU#14](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51187)
- [RTM GDR update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=3098856&kbln=en-us) - technically this is all that should be required, but you are missing out on so many other fixes from over two years of updates, this is "the absolute, I don't recommend it, bare minimum" IMHO

That's the gist of it; if you want to get into all the nitty gritty, [here is a KB article I'm stealing from Max's deleted post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1.2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server).